# I have one pixel length color image and i wanted to scale up it according to new length value.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage

So color image length will change dynamically. I will use it on the custom graph. What is the best solution for this? now i am using Resize category by extending UIImage. 
Thanks advance..

Comment: How is this different from a UIView with a background color?

Comment: the difference is that an image will be heavier in memory size...   :-)

Comment: I will create a custom bar view with 3 different color (red, green, yellow). But they have shadow corner and i cut 1 pixel length image from it. And I wanted to scale up for desired length

Comment: I did the exact same thing, it is easy using Core Graphics and CGFillRect

Comment: image have shadow corners so i also can draw corners with Core Graphics. i think this is best way but i don't have much experience on the Core Graphics

Comment: A one pixel image with shadows?  Impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this task you could use instance method of `UIImage` **stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:**. Suppose

```
[imgObj stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:4.0f topCapHeight:5.0f];
```

This method call will live 4 pix from left & right and 5 pix from top & bottom of your image and will repeat the rest image in middle.

But in your case both values will be **Zero**.

Comment: deprecated for `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`